# Setting filter on a pivot table template

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am creating a template file where a pivot table is located. 
The pivot table is then used as input for other formula.

I managed to set up the table with the proper row labels, values and report filter. 
[image]

which gives this table

[image]

The problem is that in the empty template I cannot set the filter to the value I want (in this case I want to filter only the items having the Accepted to YES), because what I have is just the content of the empty table

[image]

While I aim to obtain this

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot set a filter? You can't drag the heading "Accepted" in to the Filter box of the Pivot Fields, there is no option to do so, or a co-worker forbid it. Can you add more details or errors you are getting etc?

Comment: @TimWilkinson, see edit. I have no "YES" option in the filter pull down menu

Comment: You can't set a filter in a pivot table until it knows what value to filter by. You could achieve this via vba by catching the pivot refresh then adding the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the trick:

```
Set pT = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
With pT
    'Update the pivot table
    .PivotCache.Refresh
    'clear all filters
    .PivotFields("Accepted").ClearAllFilters
    'filters only accepted items
    .PivotFields("Accepted").CurrentPage = "YES"
End With
```